# Dask read_sql_query raised AttributeError Select object has no attribute subquery

Tags: dataframe, sqlalchemy, dask

I am trying to read data from MariaDB into Dask dataframe by using SQL, based on document from Dask, read_sql_query function takes sql parameter as a SQLAlchemy selectable.

so I tried to wrap my SQL query into a SQLAlchemy select object by following

```
sql = """

SELECT t2.wip_entity_id
       , t1.class_code
       , t1.attribute2
  FROM table_1 t1
       , table_2 t2
 WHERE t1.wip_entity_id = t2.wip_entity_id

"""
wip_entity_id = sql.column("wip_entity_id")
maria_conn_string = "xxxxx"
sel = text(sql)
sel = sel.columns()
sel = sel.alias('a')
sel = select([wip_entity_id, class_code]).select_from(sel)

data = read_sql_query(sql=sel, maria_conn_string, index_col=wip_entity_id)



AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'subquery'
```

However, if I use the same select object, and execute it directly with SQLAlchemy engine, it works

```
sel = text(sql)
sel = sel.columns()
sel = sel.alias('a')
sel = select([wip_entity_id, class_code]).select_from(sel)


engine = create_engine(maria_conn_string )
cursor = engine.execute(sel)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First some comments, `class_code` variable is never defined, and I do not understand your empty `sel.columns()`, what is it supposed to do ?

Then, if you want to select only some columns from a textual query, the simplest way is to turn it into a subquery and select columns this subquery defines.

```py
raw_stmt = """\
SELECT t2.wip_entity_id
       , t1.class_code
       , t1.attribute2
  FROM foo t1
       , bar t2
 WHERE t1.wip_entity_id = t2.wip_entity_id
"""

stmt = text(raw_stmt).columns(
    column("wip_entity_id", Integer),
    column("class_code", Integer),
    column("attribute2", Integer),
).subquery()

stmt = select([stmt.c.wip_entity_id, stmt.c.class_code])
```

This will work and emit a select over a subquery containing your SQL statement.

But why keep all columns in a textual statement to then cut it down with SQLAlchemy ? why not just simplify it to use directly ?

```py
raw_stmt = """\
SELECT t2.wip_entity_id
       , t1.class_code
  FROM foo t1
       , bar t2
 WHERE t1.wip_entity_id = t2.wip_entity_id
"""

stmt = text(raw_stmt).columns(
    column("wip_entity_id", Integer),
    column("class_code", Integer),
)
```

Here is a full demo of the original subqueried method with pandas (not dask as I do not have it installed and both `read_sql_query` funcs behave the same for such simple statements.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, column, create_engine, select, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    wip_entity_id = Column(Integer)
    class_code = Column(Integer)
    attribute2 = Column(Integer)


class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    wip_entity_id = Column(Integer)


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True, echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(bind=engine) as session:
    session.add_all(
        [
            Foo(wip_entity_id=1, class_code=101, attribute2=41),
            Bar(wip_entity_id=1),
            Foo(wip_entity_id=2, class_code=102, attribute2=42),
            Foo(wip_entity_id=3, class_code=103, attribute2=43),
            Bar(wip_entity_id=3),
        ]
    )
    session.commit()

raw_stmt = """\
SELECT t2.wip_entity_id
       , t1.class_code
       , t1.attribute2
  FROM foo t1
       , bar t2
 WHERE t1.wip_entity_id = t2.wip_entity_id
"""

stmt = (
    text(raw_stmt)
    .columns(
        column("wip_entity_id", Integer),
        column("class_code", Integer),
        column("attribute2", Integer),
    )
    .subquery("a")
)

stmt = select([stmt.c.wip_entity_id, stmt.c.class_code])

with engine.connect() as con:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(stmt, con, index_col="wip_entity_id")
```

`df` contains:

```
               class_code
wip_entity_id            
1                     101
3                     103
```